# Parallel Testing with TestNG + WebDriver XML issue?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have an issue when trying to run parallel tests with Selenium webdriver + testNG. I think my issue is with the XML, however, I am unsure if that is the issue. Below is the error message and my code were am I going wrong?

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass beforeTest
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method beforeTest but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\robertr\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--933208925\testng-customsuite.xml

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
SKIPPED: login("jane20@servicecharges.co.uk", "password1", "smith")
SKIPPED: login("rob23@orchard.co.uk", "password1", "smith")
SKIPPED: login("jeff23@hotmail.com", "password1", "smith")
SKIPPED: login("rob23@orchard.co.uk", "password1", "smith")
```

Test Code:

```
public class ParallelLogin {

    private static Logger logger1 = LogManager.getLogger("Logger1");

    WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters({"browser"})

    @BeforeClass
      public void beforeTest(String browser) {
         // If the browser is Fire fox, then do this
         DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

          if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

              driver = new FirefoxDriver();

          // If browser is IE, then do this   

          }else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) { 

              // Here I am setting up the path for my IEDriver

              System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "http://localhost/2010A15/");

              driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

          } 

          driver.get("http://localhost/2010A15/");
      }

  @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
  public void login(String sUsername, String sPassword, String sMemorableWord) throws InterruptedException {

    //Find Login Element
      driver.findElement(By.id("WEB_LoginButton")).click();

      logger1.info("Login Button Clicked");
      //Find User name Element

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_4")).sendKeys(sUsername);

      logger1.info("Username Entered");

      //Find Password Element

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_5")).sendKeys(sPassword);

      logger1.info("Password Entered");

      //Find Memorable word Element

      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_6")).sendKeys(sMemorableWord);

      logger1.info("MemorableWord Entered");

      Reporter.log("All Login Details Entered  | "); //Main Event

      WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));

      if(login.isDisplayed()){
          login.click();
          Reporter.log("Submit Button Clicked  |");
      }

        // Now check again for the login button. 
        // If login button is displayed it means that the form submission
        // is not successful and you have returned to the same page.
        // We are using a try catch block here because if the element is not found
        // if form submission is successful NoSuchElementException would be thrown.
        try {
            // Element has to be found again else StaleElementReferenceException
            // might be thrown because of page reload.
          login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));
            // if login button is found again, this means form submission is not successful
            Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
            logger1.info("Login Failed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Login button is not found. Form is submitted
           Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
           logger1.info("Submit Button Clicked and successfully logged in  |");
        }
          //Main Event is logged If Passed


          //Main Event Log Fail  

         WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));

         if(logout.isDisplayed()){
             logout.click();
             Reporter.log("Logout Button Clicked  |");
}

         try{

             logout = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_0_label"));

             Reporter.log("Logout Failed  |");


         } catch (Exception e) {

             Reporter.log("Logout Submitted  |");
             logger1.info("Logout Submitted  |");
         }
    }



      //Check Reporter Results as these will be correct. Console Results will show if code has been run and passed.





  @DataProvider(name = "Authentication")
  public static Object[][] credentials() {
    return new Object[][] { { "jane20@servicecharges.co.uk", "password1", "smith" }, { "rob23@orchard.co.uk", "password1", "smith" }, { "jeff23@hotmail.com", "password1", "smith" }, { "rob23@orchard.co.uk", "password1", "smith" }}; 
     };






        @AfterMethod
          public void afterMethod() {

             driver.close();
          }
  }
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

 <test name="FirefoxTest">

 <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />

 <classes>

 <class name="utility1.ParallelLogin" />

 </classes>

 </test>

 <test name="IETest">

 <parameter name="browser" value="ie" />

 <classes>

 <class name="utility1.ParallelLogin" />

 </classes>

 </test>
```

Comment: How are you running it ? from eclipse ? are you specifying the correct xml as testng xml while running ?

Comment: Running from Ecilpse by right click RUN as TestNG test. How do I check that I am specifying the correct xml?

Comment: that way it doesnt use any xml at all. Wait i will write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a testng.xml

1. Go to Run configuration
2. Create a new testng configuration
3. select suite radio button and specify the testng.xml file you want to use

[image]

Else if you want to just run a specific class then you can specify an optional value for the browser

```
@Parameters("browser")
public void testNonExistentParameter(@Optional("ie") String browser)
```

this way when you run without an xml it will use the optional parameter.

for more details go through the documentation  - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: I've made a new XML and configured it through run config, however, I am getting the same response?

Comment: You have to use tge configuration while running.  Otherwise if you run a single class then add the optional parameters

Comment: @Optional("chrome") String browser) works, however, If I want to run both browsers at the same time running the same test I must use the xml? or can I add chrome and firefox to @Optional?

Comment: It will work using a suite the way i mentioned.  What is the error you are getting this time

Comment: Thanks it works :). Check above for new issue I added the code. Thanks for the help @Shamik

Comment: Let me understand even when you are specifying a testng.xml via run configuration and runnning it is giving the following error ? 

Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method beforeTest

Comment: If I run it by right click run as TestNG yes it errors with that error. If I go into run configurations select suite: ParallelLogin.xml and then RUN. The test opens in both browsers and runs once. But it should run 3 times as there are 3 sets of data in the @Dataprovider object.

Comment: Methods annotated with @test is run 3 times not beforeTest methods..  I think the test is run 3 times with the test data you provided.

Comment: If I run the code from the XML suite by run config.  C:\Selenium-java-maven\workSpace\Practice-test\ParallelLogin.xml

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.48.0.0
Listening on port 2508

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 8, Failures: 2, Skips: 4
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 4

@Test should run 4x in both IE and Firefox as the Dataprovider has 4 sets of values:

Comment: maybe my @beforeclass is incorrect? I want IE and firefox to start up at the same time and run the test at the same time in the different browsers. Could be my code? Code above.

Comment: It is running 4X times for the 2 browsers. -  4 * 2=8 tests are run .. it clearly says so as per your comment


Total tests run: 8, Failures: 2, Skips: 4 Configuration Failures: 2. You have 2 Test tags in xml and in each there is a single class . So for each test tag it runs the class with the parameter value 4 times. I dont understand what is not happening as per your expectation

Comment: Sorry your correct, I've solved the issue. Still new to TestNG i've been running the tests from the class file, Didint realize you could run it from the XML also.

Comment: One last thing you might know! In the xml how would I make the same test  repeat itself(iteration)?

Comment: Invocation count will repeat the same test n no of times - like this @Test(invocationCount = 10)